# SQL - Finding inner join with only and one specific type

Tags: sql, mariadb, inner-join

I have a couple of tables in my database(`A, B`). They  1-N relationship; each 
`A` can have  N `B`.
Here is B's pseudo structure:

```
B.id , B.type , B.foreign_key(for communication between A and B), B.price
```

B.type could be between 1-8 but I want just finding A with one and only one B record with 2 (value of B.type)

for example below image is not my target result:

[image]

However, I follow up this result :

[image]

I wrote this query but it's not complete. I mean some Aid has different Btype which has value is not equal to 2 but this is not my ultimate result.

```
SELECT B.id AS Bid. B.type AS Btype , A.id AS Aid
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.foreign_key
WHERE B.B.type = 2
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why's you're query not complete?

Comment: Add some more sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Hi. This is not clear. Use enough words & sentence to exaplain. Don't try to cram things into one sentence. PS Use text, not images/links, for text. Please read & act on [mcve]. PS FKs & other constraints are not needed to query. The meanings of the base & result tables is necessary & sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this is what you're looking for. Hope it helps.

```
 select b.id as bid
      , b.type as btype 
      , a.id as aid
      , count(*) 
   from a
  inner join b on a.id = b.foreign_key
  where b.type = 2
  group by b.id, b.type, a.id
 having count(*) = 1
```